# Why can’t we perform CONFIG 1+F Takeoff in the following conditions as per the MEL?

Tags: airbus-a320, mel

I was reading in one of my company notices that we can’t perform  config 1+f takeoff on the Airbus A320 if we have the following faults.

- SFCC SLAT CHANNEL FAULT
- ADR 2 FAULT
- IR 2 INOPERATIVE

Could someone explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @mins thanks a lot any idea about the other two faults?

Comment: Please, give details, which SFCC is faulty? It is allowed to have a faulty single SFCC, but not simultaneously a faulty ADIRU of the same order 1 to 1 or 2 to 2. If you are allowed to fly, all take off configurations are functional. Otherwise it is your own company decision , I can’t tell why.

Comment: @user40476 could you provide any official reference to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all SFCC1 regulates the engines idle, lo or hi, according to the Flaps/slats configuration, for instance to provide low idle at initial descent

Also SFCC1 uses the blue hydraulic circuit for Slats, in hydraulic emergency case, only blue might be available as being generated by the RAT
  therefore SFCC1 fault is a no go, SO I assume at takeoff SFCC1 is available

SFCC1 uses primary ADIRU1 so if ADIRU1 is also faulty we go into a no go condition

Now if ADIRU2 is faulty, SFCC1 should rely on a single airspeed data, therefore if the speed is incorrect premature automatic retraction of the flaps might occur at takeoff, that is going from 1+F to 1 automatically, so take off with configuration 1+F is prohibited with these faults at takeoff